# определение класса css с помощью переменной php

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть база данных, в которой, в данном контексте, важны 2 параметра: Id и payment
и также есть сайт, который отображает всю информацию в отдельном блоке.
Цель - изменять свойство `background-color` в зависимости от значения payment.
Пробовал создавать блок и присваивать ему в класс id бд.

```
    <?php 
    if($base[6] == 'оплачено'){ ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    div. {background-color: red;} 
    </style>
    <? }  ?>
```

но не смог найти способ показать определенность класса в css
вот пример того, как выглядит часть, о которой я говорю

```css
<style type="text/css">body,
html {
  height: 100%
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

div.head {
  height: 48px;
  width: 101%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: #3C8DBC;
}

div.all_in {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.floor {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
}

tr {
  display: inline-block;
}

em {
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<?php
  include_once 'connect.php';
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `work`";
  $base = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  $base = mysqli_fetch_all($base);
?>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>main</title>
  </head>
  <div class="all_in">


    <b>Москва</b><br> Этаж 1<br>

    <?php foreach ($base as $base){ ?>

    <?php if($base[8] == "Москва"){?>

    <a href="main/update.php?id=<?= $base[0] ?>">
      <div class="floor">

        <?php 
              $cls = $base[0];
              ?>
        <div class=<?php $cls ?>>
          <tr>
            <?php 
                if($base[6] == 'оплачено'){ ?>
            <style type="text/css">
              div. {
                background-color: red;
              }
            </style>
            <? }  ?>


              <td>
                <?= $base[1] ?> <em><?= $base[7] ?>кв.м</em> </td>


          </tr>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php }else{pass;} ?>



    <?php } ?><br>
    <b>Москва</b><br> Этаж 1<br>

    <?php foreach ($base as $base){ ?>

    <?php if($base[8] == "Москва"){?>

    <a href="main/update.php?id=<?= $base[0] ?>">
      <div class="floor">

        <?php 
                      $cls = $base[0];
                      ?>
        <div class=<?php $cls ?>>
          <tr>
            <?php 
                        if($base[6] == 'оплачено'){ ?>
            <style type="text/css">
              div. {
                background-color: red;
              }
            </style>
            <? }  ?>


              <td>
                <?= $base[1] ?> <em><?= $base[7] ?>кв.м</em> </td>


          </tr>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php }else{pass;} ?>



    <?php } ?><br>

    </html>
```

Comment: лучше бы не стиль добавлял в хтмл, а просто класс в разметку

Comment: foreach ($base as $base) - как можно перечислять самого себя? поюзай foreach ($base as $sub_base) и тогда сможешь работать со строками из бд